# Parsing C# generated OpenXML xlsx with js-xlsx

Tags: javascript, c#, excel, xlsx

I generate .xlsx documents in my solution and send them to the user, when parsed with js-xlsx they have zero cells, this can be fixed by opening the generated .xlsx with Excel and saving them.

I would like to be able to parse my generated .xlsx documents directly with js-xlsx.

Code for saving to .xlsx:

```
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        workbook.SaveAs(ms);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return ms;var ms = new MemoryStream();
```

Code for opening .xlsx with js-xlsx:

```
function readBook(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
        console.log(workbook);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that c# OpenXML adds 'x:' in front of all the string xml tags, this can be fixed in js-xlsx by replacing the 'x:' tags.

simply put:

```
data = data.replace(new RegExp('x:', 'g'), '');
```

into function parse_ws_xml(data, opts, rels)
and function parse_sst_xml(data, opts)

Todo: make a fix that allows you to have strings containing 'x:' in your .xlsx file.